# WARN:Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named message in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache, hibernate-5.x, ehcache-2

Getting the warning message when deploying the application in server Jboss eap 7.1 - while starting the server below messages are shown in eclipse console log as like below,

```
 WARN  [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [SReporting.war#sReportingDS.org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
 INFO  [org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: SReporting.war#sReportingDS.org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache
 WARN  [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [SReporting.war#sReportingDS.org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
 WARN  [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [SReporting.war#sReportingDS.com.webaccess.hibernate.Mimetype]; using defaults.
 WARN  [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.EhcacheAccessStrategyFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [SReporting.war#sReportingDS.com.webaccess.hibernate.Mimetype]
 WARN  [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [SReporting.war#sReportingDS.com.webaccess.hibernate.Shortid]; using defaults.
 WARN  [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [SReporting.war#sReportingDS.com.webaccess.hibernate.CounterName]; using defaults.
 WARN  [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [SReporting.war#sReportingDS.com.webaccess.hibernate.CounterNameSummary]; using defaults.
 WARN  [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [SReporting.war#sReportingDS.com.webaccess.hibernate.CounterKey]; using defaults.
 WARN  [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [SReporting.war#sReportingDS.com.webaccess.hibernate.CountryCode]; using defaults.
 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

In POM.XML,

```
<version.ehcache-core>2.4.3</version.ehcache-core>
<version.ehcache>2.10.3</version.ehcache>
<version.hibernate-ehcache>5.1.10.Final</version.hibernate-ehcache>
<version.hibernate-jpa>1.0.1.Final</version.hibernate-jpa>
<version.hibernate-core>5.3.7.Final</version.hibernate-core>
<version.hibernate-annotations>3.5.6-Final</version.hibernate-annotations>
<version.hibernate-validator>6.0.13.Final</version.hibernate-validator>
<version.hibernate-commons-annotations>5.0.4.Final</version.hibernate-commons-annotations>
```

Also config in persistence.xml file as below,

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value ="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="16" />
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries"
                value="true" />
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName"
                value="/ehcache.xml" />
```

Configured file eh_user_cache.xml as below,

```
<ehcache xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
    updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
<diskStore path="${file.root}/eh_user_cache" />
<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true" />
<cache name="users" maxElementsInMemory="120000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="600" timeToLiveSeconds="14400" overflowToDisk="true"
        diskPersistent="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="FIFO" />
</ehcache>
```

Also configured ehcache.xml as like below,

```
<ehcache xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
    updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="${file.root}/cache" />

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true" />

    <cache
        name="persistence.unit:unitName=#SReporting.com.webaccess.hibernate.CounterKey"
        maxElementsInMemory="100000" eternal="false" overflowToDisk="false"
        timeToLiveSeconds="1200" timeToIdleSeconds="600" diskPersistent="false"
         memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

    <cache
        name="persistence.unit:unitName=#SReporting.com.webaccess.hibernate.CounterName"
        maxElementsInMemory="500000" overflowToDisk="false" timeToLiveSeconds="1200"
        timeToIdleSeconds="600" diskPersistent="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

    <cache
        name="persistence.unit:unitName=#SReporting.com.webaccess.hibernate.Shortid"
        maxElementsInMemory="500000" overflowToDisk="false" timeToLiveSeconds="1200"
        timeToIdleSeconds="600" diskPersistent="false" 
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

    <cache
        name="persistence.unit:unitName=#SReporting.com.webaccess.hibernate.CounterNameSummary"
        maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="1200"
        timeToIdleSeconds="600" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="false"
         memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

    <cache
        name="persistence.unit:unitName=#SReporting.com.webaccess.hibernate.CountryCode"
        maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false"
        diskPersistent="false"  />

    <cache
        name="persistence.unit:unitName=#SReporting.com.webaccess.hibernate.Mimetype"
        maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false"
        diskPersistent="false"  />

    <cache
        name="persistence.unit:unitName=#SReporting.org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="10000" timeToLiveSeconds="1200"
        timeToIdleSeconds="30" overflowToDisk="true" diskPersistent="false"
         memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

    <cache
        name="persistence.unit:unitName=#SReporting.org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="5000" timeToLiveSeconds="1200" overflowToDisk="true"
        diskPersistent="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
</ehcache>
```

Some more log errors:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.seam.security.permission.PersistentPermissionResolver] no permission store available - please install a PermissionStore with the name 'org.jboss.seam.security.jpaPermissionStore' if persistent permissions are required.
WARN  [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] Creating a new instance of CacheManager using the diskStorePath "/data/jboss-eap7/SR/storage/cache" which is already used by an existing CacheManager.
The source of the configuration was net.sf.ehcache.config.generator.ConfigurationSource$URLConfigurationSource@22ca95d9.
The diskStore path for this CacheManager will be set to /data/jboss-eap7/SR/storage/cache/ehcache_auto_created_1565789688939.
To avoid this warning consider using the CacheManager factory methods to create a singleton CacheManager or specifying a separate ehcache configuration (ehcache.xml) for each CacheManager instance.
2019-08-14 15:34:48,939 WARN  [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] Creating a new instance of CacheManager using the diskStorePath "/data/jboss-eap7/SR/storage/cache" which is already used by an existing CacheManager.
The source of the configuration was net.sf.ehcache.config.generator.ConfigurationSource$URLConfigurationSource@22ca95d9.
The diskStore path for this CacheManager will be set to /data/jboss-eap7/SR/storage/cache/ehcache_auto_created_1565789688939.
To avoid this warning consider using the CacheManager factory methods to create a singleton CacheManager or specifying a separate ehcache configuration (ehcache.xml) for each CacheManager instance.
```

Also properly configured ehcache.xsd file
I don't want to set the 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory' log level to ERROR:

How to resolve the problem? 
Also like to know why this is occurring?
Because of this application performance will get affected right?
Some solution would be helpful for me to resolve the problem easily and quickly. It will be helpful to understand more about the problem.Thank you.